# If I know the RMS noise/the variance of a DC measurement, can I simply subtract it from the measurement?

Tags: noise, denoising, analog-to-digital, measurement

Let's say I have an electronic system that's taking a measurement. It provides a simple bipolar excitation current to a resistive load (bipolar square wave so as to cancel out thermal emf), puts it through an analog front end and some anti-aliasing, into an ADC.

What I'm thinking is if during calibration we can just take the readings of the ADC over a long period of time on a known stable load and subtract out the DC component, all we're left with is noise, which we can calculate the variance of and store in memory. Can't we then digitally generate noise with the same variance and subtract it from our input signal when actually in use to get a signal with significantly reduced noise? From a signals/statistics standpoint, does this make any sense or is that not how noise works at all? Should I look into more complex schemes like wavelet denoising?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your intuition is correct, you need some sort of a statistical method since you don't have a way to measure the noise separately from your noisy measurement synchronously (in which case what you propose would work for an offline process).
What you do have is a measurement of the noise taken as a separate process, at a different time, which gives you a good starting point IF you assume the statistics of the noise shouldn't change much between measurements.

With these considerations in mind, you can use the noise reference statistics and do this sort of de-noising in the frequency domain, either through **Wiener filtering** approaches or **Spectral Substraction** (there are others, but those are the most common approaches).

- A naive approach could be to use your long noise-only measurement, and from that get a good estimate of the noise statistics through a Power Spectral Density, and perform Spectral Substraction on your subsequent noisy measurements.
- As for Wiener methods, here is [a good reference paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00450766/document) and [the author's MATLAB implementation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24462-wiener-filter-for-noise-reduction-and-speech-enhancement?s_tid=srchtitle)